# responsive page aligning advice

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need some help with my web design which i am trying to do as a responsive deign. The image shows my design so far and it all works well with changing to different devices.
But i want to get the key pad up under the gauges and the gauges and keypad parallel to the weather app. But its stuck down the bottom and i do not know how to get it moved up

[image]

This is the script of the row layout with the web code removed.

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-2">
      Gauge1
 </div>
 <div class="col-2">
      Gauge2
 </div>
 <div class="col-2">
      Gauge3
 </div>
 <div class="col-6">
     weather App
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-4">
      KEY Pad
 </div>
 <div class="col-8">
      nothing yet
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is being pushed down because of the height of the weather app. The weather app must have a hard coded width somewhere that is making is "skinnier" than the `col-6` you have specified. I would suggest doing something like:

Divide the main section into 2 halves, then inside the left half place a row of your gauges, and under that a row of your keypad. In the right half place your weather app.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        Gauge1
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        Gauge2
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        Gauge3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        KEY Pad
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    weather App
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked great thank, yes the weather app was fixed height but never new i could put rows with in a row. Thanks for the quick response